# Laravel query to a database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel 6 app that has a table in the database for frontend users. The users have columns for a company. I have several users that have the same value for a company. How can i create a query to the database and ask for users that have the same company field as the authenticated user?

For example:

```
$contacts = DB::table('users')->where(field company is like the field company of the authenticated user)->get()
```

or what?

Comment: Could you pls add your models / controller code ?

Comment: Depends on what your database looks like and how the current user is authenticated.

Comment: While there are other ways to do this I suggest you use a user eloquent model with a [has many through](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship to relate a user with other users. Then you can use `auth()->user()` to get the currently authenticated user and retrieve related users via the relationship

Comment: Kind of depends on how you have things set up. Knee-jerk reaction is to have a `users` table & a `companies` table. You might be able to look at a [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.

Answer (score 0):

```
$companies = DB::table('users')->where(company,/*get the the authenticated user's company here*/)->get();
```